# How to select users and groups in single query in django?

Tags: django, django-orm

I need something like this for selecting user and groups in a single query in django.

```
user = User.objects.select_related('groups').get(id=user_id)
```

I don't want to use raw queries for this.

There is another way to do this which makes two queries:

```
user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
groups = user.groups
```

Comment: What is wrong with your first example ? you just need `user.groups.all()`

Comment: have you looked at `prefetch_related`? it is supposed to be for pulling many to many relationships in one query

Answer (score 2):

You can use prefetch related in the view, and then pass it to the template

```
def view(request):
    user = User.objects.all().select_related(
    ).prefetch_related(
        'groups',
    ).get(pk=request.user.pk)
    return render(request, 'app/template.html', {
        'user': user,
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: It seems there is no way to do that in one query except raw sql or `extra`.

So if you only want to `get` one user, your second example should work.
If many users:

---

You should use [`prefetch-related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related), but in two queries.

> prefetch_related, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python. This allows it to prefetch many-to-many and many-to-one objects, which cannot be done using select_related, in addition to the foreign key and one-to-one relationships that are supported by select_related. It also supports prefetching of GenericRelation and GenericForeignKey.

...

> The additional queries in prefetch_related() are executed after the QuerySet has begun to be evaluated and the primary query has been executed.

So if you want to prefetch `groups`, it will execute two queries whether you use `all` or `get`.

Comment: It may be executing two queries, but is it slower than running the two lines the OP tried first?

Comment: @Bobort They should be the same as they basically do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You should select from Group model 'cause the relation is many to many. 
I have not tried my answer but perhaps it will work;

`group_list_with_user = Group.objects.filter(user = USERID).all()`

thereafter you can access all groups which are assigned to user and access user for example;

```
group_list_with_user[0].name  #  group name
group_list_with_user[0].user.first_name  # user's first name
```